# Invoke Lambda (inside VPC) from Lambda(No VPC).Will I get a response from the Lambda(Inside VPC) if I do not have Internet Gateway attached in the VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, vpc

I have Lambdas in NO VPC and Lambdas Located inside a VPC. The VPC is configured without an Internet Gateway attached. Am I going to get the response from the Lambda inside the VPC or I need to setup Internet connectivity to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this instance it is not really relevant if the lambda you are invoking is configured to run inside the VPC. You are never communicating directly between one Lambda function and another Lambda function. When you invoke a Lambda function you are making a call to the AWS API, and requesting AWS to start an invocation of that Lambda function. The Lambda function being invoked will then return a response to AWS, which will then return a response to the original caller that requested the invocation.

Comment: Mark B thank you for your quick response. The Lambda that I invoke is configured to run inside a VPC. So what are you telling me is that I will not find any problems because even though the Lambda that runs inside the VPC has no Internet Gateway configured , it will succeed to respond to the AWS and as a result  to the Lambda that Initiated the request.

Comment: Thank you very much for you help